# How do I select a TR but not one if its child TD with JQuery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to apply some css to some a TR and its children except for one column and its children which are checkboxes

The none of the following worked

```
 $('#myRow').not('input').css( "background-color", "#E0E0E0" ).bind('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();});

 $('#myRow').not('.myCellClass').css( "background-color", "#E0E0E0" ).bind('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();});

 $('#myRow:not(.myCellClass)').css( "background-color", "#E0E0E0" ).bind('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();});

 $('#myRow:not(input)').css( "background-color", "#E0E0E0" ).bind('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

Comment: If you select the parent, you select the children. You need to select the children, minus the one you do not want, and not the parent.

Comment: Can you post the HTML aswell?

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle... I cannot understand the question..

Comment: Please show your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Add a different class to the td you want to bind click event.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="clickable"></td>
<td class="nonclickable"></td>
<td class="clickable"></td>
</tr>
</table>

$('tr td.clickable').click(function(){ // do wathever you want. 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

event delegation is a better option:

```
$('table#mayTable').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).find('input').length) {
        // this row has inputs
        return;
    }
    // row does not have inputs
    // do what ever you like
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use `.end()` like below for a CSS change as an example.

```
$(function() {
       $("table").find("tr").css("background","red")
       .end()
       .find(".b")
        .css("background","#fff") 
 });
```

Above example in demo  http://jsbin.com/uvUTiGu/1/edit?html,css,output